# Why doesn't corona composer let you go back to the main.lua page

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When I'm using

```
composer.gotoscene("main")
```

An error pops up with the message:

> "Attempt to concatenate global 'sceneName' stack traceback".

If I use another page to redirect instead of main.lua (example "scene2") then it works.

Comment: Why you want go to main? From Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/system/composer/index.html): "The Composer lifecycle starts within main.lua. However, main.lua itself is not a Composer scen". So I don't think it is possibble to use `main` as argument for `composer.gotoscene`.

Comment: @Ronald Basically the main code for my game is in the main.lua and I want to make a separate page with a button "play" which would redirect to main.lua and start the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the code for the game should be in its own Composer scene rather than `main.lua`.  If the Composer scene with the play button is called `HomeScene.lua`, in `main.lua` you would put

```
local composer = require "composer"
composer.gotoScene( "HomeScene" )
```

This makes the scene with the play button load and appear first.  If you want to initialize your game scene before the player can have a chance to press Play and start the game, you can add `composer.loadScene("GameScene")` in `main.lua` as well.  This just creates the scene and stores it without showing it.

In `HomeScene.lua`, if the play button is a DisplayObject called `playButton`, you would do something like

```
local composer = require "composer"

local function handleTouch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        composer.gotoScene( "GameScene" )
    end
end

playButton:addEventListener( "touch", handleTouch )
```

Hope this helps.